# How to render a normal map from a camera+mesh?

Tags: normal-map

The best way to explain my question is actually this: https://youtu.be/B4j5tzAIflU?t=658

I am making grass the same way (on a plane) for a video game, but I don't know what the technique is called or how to use it in Blender (2.8).

[image: Here is what I have created so far.]

Comment: Hi. Please add a full description of what you would like into the question body itself. If that link goes down or becomes unavailable, it will be unclear what this question is about.

Comment: Please read: [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: Aaah. My bad. Lesson: Never post a thread in a hurry. I'll change the description. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: And please upvote (or at least un-downvote) my question again, 2 downvotes probably doesn't get me any further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Workbench and Eevee for creating any textures

For example normal and opacity image created with workbench https://youtu.be/yDJaSF4B138

Comment: I am speechless... This is exactly what I was looking for. I assume you uploaded this video, since it was posted -today- and otherwise is an insane coincidence: Thank you so much! Really. I was almost at a point starting to doubt if this technique was even used today or possible in Blender, since I only found (old) studio Max threads. I can't wait to start working on this. Thanks!

Comment: You answered a link-only question with a link-only answer. Please read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Have you seen the link provided as an answer? I couldn't wish for a better answer. Seriously. I understand the link-only stuff. Great link to the link-only QA, I agree. But 'sometimes' visuals are better to explain than words. This is such a case (because I didn't know the technical words involved). Please accept the exceptions. This is a happy and solved QA.

Answer (score 4):

Blender 2.8

- Properties -> Render Properties -> Render Engine = Workbench
- Properties -> Render Properties -> Lighting = MatCap
- Properties -> Render Properties -> Studio Light = check_normal+y.xer
- Properties -> Render Properties -> Color Management -> View Transform = Standard

I also recommend:

setting the scene background to #8080ff aka RGB(0.5, 0.5, 1.0) aka HSV(0.666, 0.265, 1.0), camera to orthographic, and output to a power-of-two square render.

Note: Blender shows a "Gamma Corrected" footnote on Hex numbers and gives me this strange value: #BCBCFF instead of the expected #7f7fff or ~#8080ff, I recommend using the RGB input

- Properties -> Scene -> World -> Viewport Display -> Color = RGB(0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
- Active Camera -> Properties -> Camera -> Lens -> Type = Orthographic
- Properties -> Output Properties -> Dimensions -> Resolution X = 1024
- Properties -> Output Properties -> Dimensions -> Resolution Y = 1024

Render as usual, be sure to inspect your output closely! color management is quite fickle especially since we're not representing color data

---

[image]

You can compare your render to a public example normal map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping#/media/File:Normal_map_example_with_scene_and_result.png

Comment: Perfectly listed. THNX.